# Upload a picture on Google+ API for iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, google-plus

Is there a sample project of uploading a picture on Google+ via objective-c library?

I see picassa example but is there any api to post the url on plus?

http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/

http://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/

Answer (score 1):

Here is the api developer page for Google+:

https://developers.google.com/+/api/